# Php Form Validation Class displaying errors

Tags: php, class, oop

I have the following php form Validation class, which allows me to specify which form inputs are required, the length, and whether the input should be unique.

```
<?php
class Validate {
private $_passed = false,
        $_errors = array(),
        $_db = null;

public function __construct() {
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
}

public function check($source, $items = array()) {
    foreach($items as $item => $rules) {
        foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {

            $value = trim($source[$item]);

            if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
                $this->addError("{$item} is required.");
            } else if (!empty($value)) {

                switch($rule) {
                    case 'min':
                        if(strlen($value) < $rule_value) {
                            $this->addError("{$item} must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'max':
                        if(strlen($value) > $rule_value) {
                            $this->addError("{$item} must be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'matches':
                        if($value != $source[$rule_value]) {
                            $this->addError("{$rule_value} must match {$item}.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'unique':
                        $check = $this->_db->get('users', array($item, '=', $value));
                        if($check->count()) {
                            $this->addError("{$item} is already taken.");
                        }
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
    }

    if(empty($this->_errors)) {
        $this->_passed = true;
    }

    return $this;
}

protected function addError($error) {
    $this->_errors[] = $error;
}

public function passed() {
    return $this->_passed;
}

public function errors() {
    return $this->_errors;
}
}
```

My question is, at the moment the class returns an array of errors which I'm able to foreach through:

```
foreach($validate->errors() as $error) {
    echo $error;
}
```

but I'm wondering what I can do to allow me to show the errors individually - so I could show the relevant error under the relevant field on the form - as opposed to all as a block at the top.

I hope I've been able to explain that ok!!!

Comment: always validate on the client side..

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi - why do you say that?

Comment: because validating on the client side is fast, it reduces the load on your server and it doesn't cause the user to wade through the annoying reload. @DanTemple

Comment: Agree with @DanTemple, perhaps this is a double check (to avoid inyections)... else you should validate on client side

Comment: I've just always validated server side - mostly to be sure no dodgy data is submitted

Comment: Definitely validate on the server side. Additional client side validation is nice, but should be additional. What if javascript is disabled? Always validate server side.

Comment: @DanTemple Why does the Form Validation class have access to the Database? You are creating a dependency, which is not needed. Plus you'll have a hard time testing your class. If you need some type of access to the database, then use setter/getter.

Comment: @busypeoples it's so I can check if something is unique - like a username, or email address

Comment: @DanTemple write a service class that does exactly that. You can later inject the service class via setter/getter. For example the service class might have a method called isUniqueEmail($emial) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add some kind of key to the errors array, something like this:

```
protected function addError($key, $error) {
    $this->_errors[$key] = $error;
}
```

And on every call to addError function (I think you can use $rule as key, but if not then you should add one different key for every field, for example id of the html elements or name...):

```
$this->addError($item, "{$item} is already taken.");
```

It's just an idea... let me know if it's not clear

EDITED: Changed $rule as key for $item

Comment: What would be the best way of displaying the individual errors on the form page?